# fullpage.js how to create slide anchors and scroll to them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

Using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs), how can I create anchors for slides as oppose to section anchors that are defined in the options.anchors?

The documentation says to use data-anchors but its not doing anything with the following setup. The `<a>` links just works normally by jumping to the `<div>` with the id and there is no scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage(); // initialization
});

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        <div id="slide1" class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">slide1</div>
        <div id="slide2" class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">slide2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div id="slide3" class="slide" data-anchor="slide3">slide3</div>
        <div id="slide4" class="slide" data-anchor="slide4">slide4</div>
    </div>
</div>

<ul id="main-navi">
    <li><a href="#slide1">slide1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide2">slide2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide3">slide3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide4">slide4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not explained for the `data-anchors` section in the documentation, but it is explained for the `anchors` option.

Documentation says:

> anchors: (default []) Defines the anchor links (#example) to be shown on the URL for each section. Using anchors forward and backward navigation will also be possible through the browser. This option also allows users to bookmark a specific section or slide. **Be careful! if you use anchors, they can not have the same value as any ID element on the site (or NAME element for IE).**

You are applying the same value for your `data-anchor`attribute than for the `id` tag. That's the reason why it is failing and scrolling with no animation.
Some browsers automatically scroll to elements with the same `id` or `name`attribute than the hashtag in the URL (#).

Just choose another value for your `data-anchor` attributes or change the `id` for each slide.

Comment: I think the answer is that fullpage.js does not support direct anchor links to slides. After a lot of trial and error, I finally figured out that the URL must be in the form http://domain/#section/slide you cannot have http://domain/#slide.

Comment: @Jake, fullpage.js support them, but you were doing it in the wrong way. Of course, you have to specify the section name before it, otherwise there could be conflicts between slides of different sections in case of using the default anchorlink (1, 2...). Anyway, as I said, your problem was in the use of `id` tags with the same value as your `anchorlink`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying it does not support domain/#slide which is disappointing for me. I cannot get it to work even without the id, a requirement I already know (+1).

Answer (score 2):

I know the topic is already 2 years old yet I faced the very same problem today and stumbled upon this article. Now that I´ve found a solution I thought it would be nice to share it with you guys!

```
<div class="wrap">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="nav__item active" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__item" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__item" href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__item" href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don´t forget to add the active class to the first anchor.

And for .js I just used what already comes along with the FullPage.js

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
      $('.nav__item.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.nav__item').eq(slideIndex).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

And that´s it! 
Now you have your very own slide navigation ;-)

Edit:

I guess I have misread the problem above but this also can be fixed:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="nav__item active" href="#firstPage/slide1">1</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__item" href="#firstPage/slide2">2</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__item" href="#firstPage/slide3">3</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__item" href="#firstPage/slide4">4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2"></div>
      <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide3"></div>
      <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide4"></div>
    </div>
</div>

 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', thirdPage'],
    afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
      $('.nav__item.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.nav__item').eq(slideIndex).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I just added an array of anchors (you can also read this up in the [FullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/)

I don´t know if this is the cleanest solution but it works ;)