# How to create own link on section Using Fullpage JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I know about that topic -- [fullpage.js how to create slide anchors and scroll to them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156311/fullpage-js-how-to-create-slide-anchors-and-scroll-to-them)

But I need to create anchor for sections.

Here's my [page](http://imatte.ru/work/beauty/).

Scroll buttons at the bottom off every sections should be scroll to the next section, but I can't understand how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is explained [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-links-to-sections-or-slides) and you even [have examples of it available](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples).

You are now initializing fullPage.js without the anchors option, in fact, without any single option:

```
$('#wrap').fullpage();
```

Just add the anchors option as detailed in the docs, for example:

```
 $('#wrap').fullpage({
      anchors: ['first', 'second', 'third']
 });
```